# MTCNN does not use GPU on first detection but does on following detections

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I have tensorflow 2.0 -gpu installed. I am doing face detection using MTCNN. On the first call to detect the face it takes 3.86 seconds. On the next call it takes only .049 seconds. I suspect it is not using the GPU on the first call but it does on the second call. I know MTCNN does  import tensorflow but I do not understand why the GPU is not used on the first call. Code is below.

```
import time
from mtcnn import MTCNN
import cv2
#********first run of image detection - note resulting process time- think not using gpu
detector = MTCNN()
img_file=r'c:\Temp\people\storage\1.jpg'   
img = cv2.imread(img_file, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)        
start=time.time()
detector.detect_faces(img)
stop=time.time()
duration = stop-start
print(duration)
# rerun image detection on the same image - note duration much less must be using gpu
start=time.time()
detector.detect_faces(img)
stop=time.time()
duration = stop-start
print(duration)
Using TensorFlow backend.
3.8625590801239014
0.049181222915649414
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does use GPU on the first call. The main overhead in the allocation of model's parameters and creation of the computation graph in memory. You can use a small "dummy" image first (it doesn't have to be full-size) to allow the ops to be formed and variables to be placed on the GPU, then continue using the actual images.

Comment: I thought that too. However if the second time you call detect with an  image different than the first image the time duration is still large.

Comment: I set all images to 224 X 224 and did 4 images resultant durations were 3.6, .023, ,22,,22,,09 so I guess you were right - Thank you